# Fourteen indviduals are to be divided into comittee of three, four and seven members

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can the individuals be grouped?

$${14\choose3}\cdot{11\choose4}\cdot{7\choose7}$$

Is this the right way to approach this?

Comment: Yes, that looks right to me!

Comment: @Billy Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your answer is fine. It reduces to the [*multinomial coefficient*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

$$\binom{14}{3,4,7}=\frac{14!}{3!\,4!\,7!}$$

if you write it out and perform the most obvious cancellations:

$$\binom{14}3\binom{11}4\binom77=\frac{14!}{3!\,\color{green}{11!}}\cdot\frac{\color{green}{11!}}{4!\,\color{magenta}{7!}}\cdot\frac{\color{magenta}{7!}}{7!\,0!}=\frac{14!}{3!\,4!\,7!}\;.$$

Comment: @Thomas: No, that was a mental hiccup.

Comment: Really, Brian, cyan on white? Even I had trouble reading this. You'd better hope that Asaf doesn't come across this answer.

Comment: @Rick: I prefer red, but I was consciously avoiding it for precisely the reason that you have in mind, blue doesn’t contrast well with black, and yellow is worse than cyan. It’s a toss-up between green, which has mediocre contrast with black, and cyan, which to my eye is brilliantly present but hard to read against the white background. I’ve changed it to green, but I’m not at all sure that it’s a net improvement.

Comment: It's a bit better, at least for me. I've never tried it and frankly don't know how I'd do it in LaTeX, but I recall having seen cancelling strikethroughs as one might do on paper. Maybe I'll go over to the TeX SE site and ask.

Comment: @Rick: There’s a `\cancel{}` that produces a diagonal cancellation, but it’s not in the MathJax library.

Comment: Well, it can be brought into MathJax on demand by using `\require{cancel}`, but the cancel package is of limited use for our purposes. I was amused that the documentation ends with the sentence "I don't recommend that you use this package at all".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simplest written as $\,\dfrac{14!}{7! \,4!\, 3!}.\,$

The factorial $N! = N.(N-1)\cdot (N-2) .. 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ being the number of permutations possible for a group of size $N.$

Comment: But 14!/(7! 4! 3!) is the same as what the original poster wrote, isn't it?

Comment: @ Johannes Thank you for helping me out

Comment: @Billy -- correct, but I thought it more insightful to represent it in this simple form.